# Swift Trying to link a tap event on a table view cell to a controller method

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I am new to swift and havne't programmed in objective C. So i'm new :-)
trying to do something fairly simple. Link a table view cell click to call a method in the controller like so
http://prntscr.com/4m9kf7

Edit:

i have these methods in my MasterController

```
  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) {
```

I have added breakpoints in all 4 of them.
and when clicking on the cell it doesn't stop in either of them.
See Screen shot:

http://prntscr.com/4m9ql0

Comment: it's in the screen shot, tried to connect the method via the connection assitant

Comment: You need to implement the didSelectRowAtIndex path delegate method and put your handling code inside that method.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You need to implement the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` delegate method and put your handling code inside it.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
     //CODE TO BE RUN ON CELL TOUCH
}
```

Comment: Hi @Woodstock, thanks for the quick response. it still deosnt work, I have edited the question

Comment: @WebQube I think you have to change the signature of the method to remove the '!' symbols in the latest Xcode beta - please use my updated answer

Comment: for `swift3` it's `override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {`

Answer (score 1):

For Swift 4:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print("row selected: \(indexPath.row)")
}
```